# Python - cross array multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I'm developing a model based on neural network principals.
I have an entry layer, weights and an output layer:

```
[1,2] -- [ [1,1] , [1,1] ] --> [3,3]
```

[image: Simple Neural Network based on two layers and one weight layer]

My question is whether Python has a simple way (with numpy) to compute the output layers without doing loops and loops.

The current implementation is:

```
for i in range(0,number_of_out_neurons):
    out_neuron_adder_toWrap = weights[i] * all_input_layer
    out_neuron[i] = sum(out_neuron_adder)         <-- wrapping
```

Comment: Could you implement the loopy version, so that we would have a better idea on what exactly you have in mind and would additionally helps us cross-check against any vectorized approach that could be suggested?

Comment: Considering this is just an addition of each `input` multiplied by each `weight`, you can just do a `dot-product`. But this will only work if the input dimensions work with the weight dimensions

Comment: Could you also add their shape information (shapes of input arrays)? Would be best to add a minimal representative sample case with numeric data and the final output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this with `numpy.dot`

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: a
Out[2]: array([1, 2])
In [3]: b
Out[3]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1]])
In [4]: np.dot(a,b)
Out[4]: array([3, 3])
```

Here is more [Reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) about `numpy.dot`

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. The only issue is if @hugodecasta has a weight of unequal dimensions, i.e. he has 3 outputs and 2 inputs

Comment: For same input/output shapes it work but for like 3/2 it fail as expected but i thinck it should be easy to fix that

Comment: The rule already implemented in `numpy.dot`. We don't want to worry about that.

Comment: Yes but the problem is still here
`[1,2,3] DOT [ [1,1,1], [1,1,1] ]`
Does not wrok... because the two vectors are not aligned

Comment: My miss sory
Instead of using `[1,2,3] DOT [ [1,1,1], [1,1,1] ]` we have to use 
`[ [1,1,1], [1,1,1] ] DOT [1,2,3]`

Comment: The rule is `a/b` multiply with `c/d`. Then `a` should equal to `c`. The last problem you said. First one is `3/1` and `2/3` and second one is `2/3` and `3/1`. So i hope you understand the issue.

Comment: I mean `[1,2,3]` is `3/1` and `[ [1,1,1], [1,1,1] ]` is `2/3`